# Slow background position change in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<body onload ="start()">

<div id="masc">
<div id="cont">

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

I run into a problem with background-position change in Microsoft Edge. It is slow. Other browsers is just fine. Here is my sketch. Maybe it is because of the width of the #cont div. It is preaty big. But in other browsers there is no problem...

```js
function start(){
    var cont = document.getElementById("cont");
    for(var i = 0; i<1440; i++){
        var celda = document.createElement("DIV");
        celda.className = "celda";
        celda.id=Math.floor(i/60) + ":" + (i%60);
        celda.innerHTML = Math.floor(i/60) + ":" + (i%60);
        celda.offsetRight = function(){return (this.offsetLeft + this.offsetWidth + (this.style.borderWidth*2));};
        cont.appendChild(celda);

    }
}
```

```css
.celda {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:5px;
    border:solid 1px red;
    width:30px;
    height:80px;
    margin-top: 225px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 40px;
    background-image : url("difusor_cerrado.png");
    background-position : 0px -80px;
    background-repeat : no-repeat ;
}

.celda:hover{
background-position : 0px 0px;
}


#cont {
    margin-top:44%;
    background : transparent; ;
    display:table;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height:350px;
    position:relative;

    border:solid 1px black;

}
#masc {
    width:1000px;
    height:800px;
    margin:auto;
    overflow-y :hidden;
    overflow-x : auto;
    border:solid 1px blue;
    background-image : url("hierva.png");
    background-position : 0% 99%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

[image][image]
This are the images I am using as backgrounds

Comment: Maybe it has to do with creating 1440 divs and applying 1440 background images...

Comment: Yes, I know that. But why there is problem in IE? Maybe I should try preload the images. Or this is because of scrollbar? Because when I set overflow to visible, it works fine. Please, could  you  give me some more detailed explanation.

Comment: 1440 images :) In IE :) And you expect that to be fluid :) I'm amazed it is fluid in any browser to begin with

Comment: There are total 2 images. One of which doesn't change. The other is set like background for 1440 divs. On rollover the background is not changed, it's repositioned. I dont think that the image is stored 1440 times to use in 1440 different places. As much as I know it is stored once and later reused.

Comment: Oh yes, obviously, the image is loaded only once and stored once in the cache. But it is used 1440 times in the dom, and repainted 1440 times on resize nonetheless. Which requires a lot of resources and a (cough, cough) very optimized browser.